# C# Displaying text (including text from a textbox) when a button is pressed

Tags: c#, user-interface, fonts, textbox, label

The program below is an incomplete solution to an assignment that creates a display that gives the user several options for how some text will be displayed. There is a combo box that can be set to "Bold" or "Italic", radio buttons for either small or large sized font, and a text field where the user can enter the name of a capital city. There are three buttons, labeled France, England, and Mexico. When a button is pushed text is to be displayed that is formatted based on the options the user has chosen. For example, suppose the user enters Paris in the text box, chooses the bold font from the combo box, and selects the large size radio button. When the France button is pressed text should be displayed in a label that says "**The capital of France is Paris**".

The trouble is the word Paris should be taken from the text box and I am not sure how to get this to be part of the string in the label. In the code below, my plan was to, for each button, create some IF statements for each possible combination of text styles (Bold/Large, Bold/Small, Italic/Large, Italic/Small). But I am not sure of the syntax for that and not sure how to include the text from the text box as part of the string. Any help or guidance on how to get the buttons to display the appropriate message would be greatly appreciated.

I should note that the IF statement lines in the code below are flagged in Visual studio, but no helpful info was provided.

```
namespace HW_Ch9_20
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button france = new Button();
    private Button england = new Button();
    private Button mexico = new Button();

    private RadioButton large = new RadioButton();
    private RadioButton small = new RadioButton();

    private ComboBox style = new ComboBox();

    private TextBox capital = new TextBox();

    private Label styleLable = new Label();
    private Label sizeLable = new Label();
    private Label enterCapital = new Label();
    private Label display = new Label();



    public Form1()
    {
        france.Text = "France";
        england.Text = "England";
        mexico.Text = "Mexico";
        large.Text = "Large";
        small.Text = "Small";
        //style.Text = "Select a style";
        styleLable.Text = "Style";
        sizeLable.Text = "Size";
        enterCapital.Text = "Enter capital";
        capital.Text = "";
        display.Text = "";


        Size = new Size(800, 400);
        display.Size = new Size(250, 200);

        france.Location = new Point(250, 30);
        england.Location = new Point(330, 30);
        mexico.Location = new Point(410, 30);
        large.Location = new Point(350, 250);
        small.Location = new Point(350, 275);
        style.Location = new Point(80, 68);
        styleLable.Location = new Point(40, 70);
        capital.Location = new Point(560, 150);
        sizeLable.Location = new Point(310, 265);
        enterCapital.Location = new Point(580, 130);
        display.Location = new Point(240, 80);

        style.Items.Add("Bold");
        style.Items.Add("Italic");

        Controls.Add(france);
        Controls.Add(england);
        Controls.Add(mexico);
        Controls.Add(large);
        Controls.Add(small);
        Controls.Add(style);
        Controls.Add(capital);
        Controls.Add(styleLable);
        Controls.Add(sizeLable);
        Controls.Add(enterCapital);
        Controls.Add(display);


        france.Click += new EventHandler(france_Click);
        england.Click += new EventHandler(england_Click);
        mexico.Click += new EventHandler(mexico_Click);

        string capitalText = capital.Text;

        void france_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(large.Checked && style.SelectedText == "Bold")
                private Font largeBold = new Font(("The capital of France is {0}", capitalText), 24, FontStyle.Bold);

        }

        void england_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        void mexico_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Well for starters, your if statement isn't compiling because you declare `largeBold` as `private` and access modifiers are not allowed for variables inside methods.

Comment: Thanks. The if statement was still have errors because it still does not compile

Comment: Its because u forgot `String.Format` before `("The capital of France is {0}", capitalText)`.

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you again. Although it says that variable capitalText does not exist in the current context. Should I be declaring it in a different spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, your if statement isn't compiling because you declare `largeBold` as `private` and access modifiers are not allowed for variables inside methods.

This is how I'd do it:

```
void france_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int fontSize = 24;
    FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyle.Regular | FontStyle.Bold;

    // Set the font size
    if (largeRadioButton.Checked) // Large font size
    {
        fontSize = 24;
    }
    else if (smallRadioButton.Checked) // Small font size
    {
        fontSize = 16;
    }

    // Set the font style and font weight
    if (styleComboBox.SelectedText == "Bold") // Bold font
    {
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
    }
    else if (styleComboBox.SelectedText == "Italic") // Italic font
    {
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic;
    }

    // Apply the font style.
    displayLabel.Font = new Font("Arial", fontSize, fontStyle);
    // Set the text.
    displayLabel.Text = String.Format("The capital of France is {0}", capitalTextBox.Text);

}
```

Here u simply go through what is set by your controls and set the font size, style and weight of the `displayLabel` before you display the text on the label.

Note that I added a postfix on the variables which indicate what kind of control they are for better readability. This is just my personal preference however.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: This does not allow the font style to be changed. It will be regular and bold no matter what is selected in the combo box.

Comment: It might be because `styleComboBox.SelectedText` is not actually what you selected in the comboBox and neither of the if statements are executed. Maybe you are looking for `styleComboBox.Text`

Comment: I found the error that was causing the issue. Thank you very much for your help and thanks for the tip about the naming conventions.